# Conditional Django form validation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, model

For a Django project, I have a customized User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('e-mail address'),
                              unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'),
                                  max_length=150,
                                  blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'),
                                  max_length=150,
                                  blank=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I'm creating a new user registration form:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    auto_password = forms.BooleanField(label=_('Generate password and send by mail'),
                                       required=False,
                                       initial=True)
    password = forms.CharField(label=_('Password'),
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_('Repeat password'),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff',
                  'is_superuser')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Passwords don't match."))
        return cd['password2']
```

My form has a `auto_password` boolean field. When this checkbox is set, the `password` and `password2` fields must not be checked, as their content (or the absence of content) has no importance. On the opposite, when the `auto_password` checkbox is unset, the `password` and `password2` must be checked.

Is there a way to optionnally disable the Django form checks whenever needed?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add this to the the condition in the `clean` method:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    auto_password = forms.BooleanField(
        label=_('Generate password and send by mail'),
        required=False,
        initial=True
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Password'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Repeat password'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff',
                  'is_superuser')

    def clean(self):
        data = super().clean()
        if not data['auto_password'] and data['password'] != data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Passwords don't match.'))
        return data
```

The `not data['auto_password']` will thus return `False` in case the checkbox is checked, and in that case the the check of `data['password'] != data['password2']` will not run, nor will it raise a `ValidationError`.

You can also remove the `required=True` properties, and check if the `password` contains at least one character by checking it truthiness:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    auto_password = forms.BooleanField(
        label=_('Generate password and send by mail'),
        # no required=True
        initial=True
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Password'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Repeat password'),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff',
                  'is_superuser')

    def clean(self):
        data = super().clean()
        manual = not data['auto_password']
        if manual and not data['password']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Password is empty.'))
        if manual and data['password'] != data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Passwords don't match.'))
        return data
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and code proposal.

Unfortunatelly, Django makes another check prior to the clean() methods.

When the field is empty, it then states "This field is required." for both password and password2. This is the check I'd like to optionally disable.

Comment: @amigne: then you include that in the check, and remove the `required=True`.

Comment: I was looking for short-circuiting the check on demand. But your proposal (disabling the check and implement it whenever neede) is definitelly much better.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just include it in your logic?

```
if not cd['auto_password'] and (cd['password'] != cd['password2']):
    raise forms.ValidationError(_("Passwords don't match."))
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, Django makes another check prior to the clean() methods.

When the field is empty, it then states "This field is required." for both password and password2. This is the check I'd like to optionally disable.